# How do I make a Promise typesafe in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-promise

Promises seem to be kind of type-unsafe in Typescript. This simple example shows that `resolve` accepts `undefined`, whereas `Promise.then` seems to infer the argument to be non-`undefined`:

```
function f() {
  return new Promise<number>((resolve) => {
    resolve(undefined)
  })
}

f().then((value) => { 
  console.log(value+1)
})
```

(tried in my current project an on http://www.staging-typescript.org/play).

Apparently, Typescript infers the type of `value` to be `number`, instead of `number | PromiseLike<number> | undefined`.

This may be a current Typescript issue, but...

What is an appropriate workaround? I'd like the compiler to warn me that `value` may be undefinded!

A very simple solution could be to write

```
f().then((value:number | undefined) => { 
  console.log(value+1) // now I have: Object is possibly 'undefined'
})
```

but that requires me to actively think about the problem at every call site.

**EDIT** (current status): Following the [solution given by @JerMah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61949212/199201), I wrapped the `Promise` creation in a generic function:

```
function makePromise<T>(executor: (resolve: (value: T) => void,
                                   reject: (reason?: any) => void) => void)
{
  return new Promise<T>(executor);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean that it seems to infer that it is non undefined?  Other than that the logic that acts upon it would not work if it was not defined as a number

Comment: @Taplar I did not say that Typescript "seems" to infer that `value` is not undefined, I said that it _does_. OItherwise I'd get the "Object is possibly 'undefined'" diagnostic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could manually set the signature of the resolve function. That way you cannot pass it undefined.

```
function f() {
  return new Promise<number>((resolve: (arg0: number) => void) => {    
    resolve(undefined); // Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
  });
}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlgJQKZQK4CcwFUwBMkBmcYSuMAvDABQCUFAfDKnocaQLABQXBzwUccDAK0YAby4wpMdCgxgYJAO4wACuhABbOBCQAeMKk0AjJOnpUqsiCAA2ANyQAuagEN0AcwAMLwybN05Iz2IHC4gYxi0jCS0TJINg5IVMz4RCThsVIAvjRc2Vw8tAB0UAAWSGCW9q62qEgR4jGcUqCQdkjFtiAeVDV1SADUAIx5nLlAA)

Comment: It would be nice if the typescript compiler knew to do this implicitly.

Comment: @BuhBuh They once tried to change it but it broke a lot of things. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/22772

Comment: Apparently, this seems to work. Nice. It took me a while to figure out which way the assignment and "narrowing" works in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible with current TypeScript. However, at the cost of a little more verbosity, you can change your code to something like this:

```
const iReturnUndefined = () => undefined

function f() {
    return new Promise<number>((resolve) => {
        const resolvedVal: number = iReturnUndefined() // Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.

        resolve(resolvedVal)
    })
}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=3#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlgJQKZQK4CcwFUwBMkBmcYSuMAvDABQCUFAfDKnocaQLABQXBzwUccDAK0YAby4wpMdCgxgYJAO4wACuhABbOBCQAeMKk0AjJOnpUqsiCAA2ANyR1yjCZ2keYoSLGt3HuABqAIa2AFyKRqboFPDIaJg4+EQkuLSSnhmeMkg2DkhWuf6kIbY0WTAAvuWclVw8tAB0UAAWSGCW9qGoTgziMBneeUiNtiAA5lRdtj0A1ACMNdVAA)

Comment: What does that help, exactly? The compiler now gives the error message you cited. Why isn't this possible with Typescript? Any references?